# Templated object generation in python

Tags: python, design-patterns

What is a good design pattern to implement templated object generation (not sure that's the name) in python?

By that, I mean having a function such as:

```py
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

def mk_templated_obj_factory(template: T) -> Callable[..., T]:
    """Returns a f(**kwargs) function that returns an object of type T created by a template of the same type."""
```

Python has templated strings. Something like `"this {is} a {template}".format' would be how one could achieve the above. If we want to get a "proper" function that has a signature (useful for a user so they know what arguments they need to provide!), we could do this:

```py
from inspect import signature, Signature, Parameter
from operator import itemgetter
from typing import Callable

f = "hello {name} how are you {verb}?".format

def templated_string_func(template: str) -> Callable:
    """A function making templated strings. Like template.format, but with a signature"""
    f = partial(str.format, template)
    names = filter(None, map(itemgetter(1), string.Formatter().parse(template)))
    params = [Parameter(name=name, kind=Parameter.KEYWORD_ONLY) for name in names]
    f.__signature__ = Signature(params)

    return f

f = templated_string_func("hello {name} how are you {verb}?")
assert f(name='Christian', verb='doing') == 'hello Christian how are you doing?'
assert str(signature(f)) == '(*, name, verb)'
```

But would if we want to make `dict` factories? Something having this behavior:

```py
g = templated_dict_func(template={'hello': '$name', 'how are you': ['$verb', 2]})
assert g(name='Christian', verb='doing') == {'hello': '$name', 'how are you': ['doing', 2]}
```

What about other types of objects?

It seems like something that would have a solid design pattern...

Comment: Seems like you might be looking for the `cookiecutter` library?

Comment: Or just possibly metaclasses.  But be very sure you need metaclasses before you use them

Comment: Do you mean `assert g(name='Christian', verb='doing') == {'hello': 'Christian', 'how are you': {'doing'}}`?

Comment: Yes @Oli, you're right. Corrected this.

Comment: @OneCricketeer -- as far as I know, `cookiecutter` would be an "instance" of this, but just for files, and even more specifically for project files. Are you referring to some more general tooling in its entrails, or design pattern they're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using decorators to register your template function generating functions in a dictionary that maps from types to the functions that handle them. The dictionary is needed in order to be able to template objects of any type in an extensible way, without writing all the templating logic in a single big function, but instead adding handling logic for new types as needed.

The core code is in the `Templater` class, just grouped here for organisation:

```
class Templater:
    templater_registry: dict[type, Callable[[Any], TemplateFunc]] = {}

    @classmethod
    def register(cls, handles_type: type):
        def decorator(f):
            cls.templater_registry[handles_type] = f
            return f

        return decorator
    ...
```

Where `TemplateFunc` is defined as `Generator[str, None, Callable[..., T]]`, a generator that yields `str`s and returns a function that returns some type `T`. This is chosen so that the template handlers can yield the names of their keyword arguments and then return their template function. The `Templater.template_func` method uses a something of type `TemplateFunc` to generate a function with the correct signature.

The `register` decorator presented above is written such that:

```
@Templater.register(dict)
def templated_dict_func(template: dict[K, V]):
    pass
```

is equivalent to:

```
def templated_dict_func(template: dict[K, V]):
    pass

Templater.templater_registry[dict] = templated_dict_func
```

The code for templating any type is fairly self-explainatory:

```
class Templater:
    ...

    @classmethod
    def template_func_generator(cls, template: T) -> TemplateFunc[T]:
        # if it is a type that can be a template
        if type(template) in cls.templater_registry:
            # then return the template handler
            template_factory = cls.templater_registry[type(template)]
            return template_factory(template)
        else:
            # else: an empty generator that returns a function that returns the template unchanged,
            # since we don't know how to handle it
            def just_return():
                return lambda: template
                yield  # this yield is needed to tell python that this is a generator

            return just_return()
```

The code for templating strings is fairly unchanged, except that the argument names are yielded instead of put in the function signature:

```
@Templater.register(str)
def templated_string_func(template: str) -> TemplateFunc[str]:
    """A function making templated strings. Like template.format, but with a signature"""
    f = partial(str.format, template)
    yield from filter(None, map(itemgetter(1), string.Formatter().parse(template)))

    return f
```

The `list` template function could look like this:

```
@Templater.register(list)
def templated_list_func(template: list[T]) -> TemplateFunc[list[T]]:
    entries = []
    for item in template:
        item_template_func = yield from Templater.template_func_generator(item)

        entries.append(item_template_func)

    def template_func(**kwargs):
        return [
            item_template_func(**kwargs)
            for item_template_func in entries
        ]

    return template_func
```

Although, if you cannot guarantee that every template function can handle extra arguments, you need to track which arguments belong to which elements and only pass the necessary ones. I use the `get_generator_return` utility function (defined later on) to capture both the yielded values and the return value of the recursive calls.

```
@Templater.register(list)
def templated_list_func(template: list[T]) -> TemplateFunc[list[T]]:
    entries = []
    for item in template:
        params, item_template_func = get_generator_return(Templater.template_func_generator(item))
        params = tuple(params)
        yield from params

        entries.append((item_template_func, params))

    def template_func(**kwargs):
        return [
            item_template_func(**{arg: kwargs[arg] for arg in args})
            for item_template_func, args in entries
        ]

    return template_func
```

The `dict` handler is implemented similarly. This system could be extended to support all kinds of different objects, including arbitrary `dataclass`es and more, but I leave that as an exercise for the reader!
Here is the entire working example:

```
import string
from functools import partial
from inspect import Signature, Parameter
from operator import itemgetter
from typing import Callable, Any, TypeVar, Generator, Tuple, Dict, List
from collections import namedtuple

T = TypeVar('T')
U = TypeVar('U')


def get_generator_return(gen: Generator[T, Any, U]) -> Tuple[Generator[T, Any, U], U]:
    return_value = None

    def inner():
        nonlocal return_value
        return_value = yield from gen

    gen_items = list(inner())

    def new_gen():
        yield from gen_items
        return return_value

    return new_gen(), return_value


# TemplateFunc: TypeAlias = Generator[str, None, Callable[..., T]]
TemplateFunc = Generator[str, None, Callable[..., T]]

class Templater:
    templater_registry: Dict[type, Callable[[Any], TemplateFunc]] = {}

    @classmethod
    def register(cls, handles_type: type):
        def decorator(f):
            cls.templater_registry[handles_type] = f
            return f

        return decorator

    @classmethod
    def template_func_generator(cls, template: T) -> TemplateFunc[T]:
        if type(template) in cls.templater_registry:
            template_factory = cls.templater_registry[type(template)]
            return template_factory(template)
        else:
            # an empty generator that returns a function that returns the template unchanged,
            # since we don't know how to handle it
            def just_return():
                return lambda: template
                yield  # this yield is needed to tell python that this is a generator

            return just_return()

    @classmethod
    def template_func(cls, template: T) -> Callable[..., T]:
        gen = cls.template_func_generator(template)
        params, f = get_generator_return(gen)

        f.__signature__ = Signature(Parameter(name=param, kind=Parameter.KEYWORD_ONLY) for param in params)
        return f


@Templater.register(str)
def templated_string_func(template: str) -> TemplateFunc[str]:
    """A function making templated strings. Like template.format, but with a signature"""
    f = partial(str.format, template)
    yield from filter(None, map(itemgetter(1), string.Formatter().parse(template)))

    return f


K = TypeVar('K')
V = TypeVar('V')


@Templater.register(dict)
def templated_dict_func(template: Dict[K, V]) -> TemplateFunc[Dict[K, V]]:
    DictEntryInfo = namedtuple('DictEntryInfo', ['key_func', 'value_func', 'key_args', 'value_args'])
    entries: list[DictEntryInfo] = []
    for key, value in template.items():
        key_params, key_template_func = get_generator_return(Templater.template_func_generator(key))
        value_params, value_template_func = get_generator_return(Templater.template_func_generator(value))
        key_params = tuple(key_params)
        value_params = tuple(value_params)
        yield from key_params
        yield from value_params

        entries.append(DictEntryInfo(key_template_func, value_template_func, key_params, value_params))

    def template_func(**kwargs):
        return {
            entry_info.key_func(**{arg: kwargs[arg] for arg in entry_info.key_args}):
                entry_info.value_func(**{arg: kwargs[arg] for arg in entry_info.value_args})
            for entry_info in entries
        }

    return template_func


@Templater.register(list)
def templated_list_func(template: List[T]) -> TemplateFunc[List[T]]:
    entries = []
    for item in template:
        params, item_template_func = get_generator_return(Templater.template_func_generator(item))
        params = tuple(params)
        yield from params

        entries.append((item_template_func, params))

    def template_func(**kwargs):
        return [
            item_template_func(**{arg: kwargs[arg] for arg in args})
            for item_template_func, args in entries
        ]

    return template_func


g = Templater.template_func(template={'hello': '{name}', 'how are you': ['{verb}', 2]})
assert g(name='Christian', verb='doing') == {'hello': 'Christian', 'how are you': ['doing', 2]}
print(g.__signature__)
```

Comment: Great stuff @Oli. I've +1, but will have to first try and read through before I accept. I should be able to figure out what you're doing, but for sure, some explanations would help and bring the answer more educational value.

Comment: @thorwhalen explanations added!

Comment: Thanks @Oli -- will look at this. Note one thing: There's no `TypeAlias` in current python version. That comes (soon!!) in `3.10`.

Comment: in fact there were a few more things that made it 3.8 incompatible. I edited the last "everything" block of code to be 3.8+ compatible.